I'm trying to import data into SQL Server using Azure Data Studio's Import function - it's seeing data as delimiters incorrectly
I have a file with one single column called GUIDS.
Each line has data in the format as below
00-15-BC-00-19-09-2B-E4

Normally I use the SQL Server Import extension and import the data fine. But with this specific data it thinks the hyphens are delimiters and is trying to split the data into 8 columns.
Any suggestions how I can resolve this?
I've tried creating derived columns - I've read through blog posts, but no one seems to address this issue. There seems to be no way to tell it to ignore the hyphens - but we need them.

Is it possible to use fixed-width columns instead of separated columns?

Seems like, at this time, ADS' import tool doesn't have the option to define the delimiter. So there's no work around. You'd be better off checking if there's a feature request for it on the repository and, if not, asking for it; that (likely) won't be a quick turnaround. In the mean time, you'll likely be better off with a BULK INSERT or something.

Append a comma in each row to create two columns. Or use better tools for importing, even the old ssms does this better

I concur with @siggemannen. SSMS Import and Export Data wizard is using SSIS behind the scenes. So, it can easily handle your scenario.

In Azure Data Studio Import flat file wizard Or SSMS import flat file option doesn't give us option to set the delimiter I will auto detect (repetitive special characters) as delimiters.
To workaround this you can register use , at the and it will use it as default delimiter to separate the column and get the value as individual column as suggested by @siggemannen
Or you can use SQL import wizard option from SMSS with flat file it will provide you row delimiter and column delimiter option.

